# TableWrapData: widgets won't left align properly

Tags: layout, widget

My program uses TableWrapLayout with numColumns set to 2.  I then have the following code: (background colors are set to show you that the widgets aren't using the blank space).

```
    Label label = toolkit.createLabel(container, "Resource Type":);
    label.setLayoutData(new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.LEFT,TableWrapData.MIDDLE));
label.setBackground(DiagramSettings.NODE_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    resourceComboMenu = new Combo(container, SWT.READ_ONLY);
resourceComboMenu.setBackground(DiagramSettings.NODE_BACKGROUND_COLOR); 
    resourceComboMenu.setLayoutData(new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.LEFT,TableWrapData.MIDDLE));
```

[image]

However as you can see in the picture the combo box refuses to left align properly.  But that I mean I want it to start right after the label, not have a bunch of blank space.

One workaround would be to put the row inside it's own Composite just like I do Resource Icon and Geolocation.  But I feel like I shouldn't need to since the widgets on this row equals the number of columns set by the layout.  I've created this workaround for now but would like to understand this TableWrapData behavior for the future.

Any insight would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pretty much answered my question in the question.  The composite that contains everything in the picture had TableWrapData with columns set to 2.  TableWrapData essentially draws a straight, vertical line between each column then makes sure widgets from one column don't cross it.

So to fix this (like I mentioned in my question) you simply make another composite with nested widgets (which in the case would be the resource type label and resourceComboMenu).  I just didn't realize that is what you're supposed to do.